# View layouts in Android GUI

Tags: android, android-layout

Seriously, this Android GUI and layout system is getting on my nerves. I can't make simple TextFields without having the whole layout alter itself and stack on top of each other.

For example, I made 9 textfields right below each other and changed their text in the XML. Then, when I went to modify their @+id/ the entire layout itself changed! I looked at the graphical layout and the text fields were stacked on top of each other and pushed to the top of the screen!

I mean how can changing the ID cause any layout differences???? I'm new to Android, but this doesn't make sense to me, it is very discouraging and frustrating. It feels like I have to do multiple trial and errors when making interfaces and not use a logical train of thought.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Many thousands of developers manage just fine. I suspect that the problem might be with your approach, especially as you seem to think the fault lies with Android - evidenced by you not showing us the XML you are struggling with.  Rather than rant about something that works just fine, how about asking a specific focused question?  You have not given enough information to respond effectively but I suspect that `RelativeLayout` might be a good fit for your goal. Finally, changing the ID does **not** cause the layout to reflow but again, without see the XML, who knows what you've done?

Comment: Ya sorry I was just frustrated. I am using a linear layout since I thought that would be easier.

Comment: Selecting for "easier" makes no sense since the different layouts are designed to accomplish very different things.  A LinearLayout will stack controls exactly as you describe - it providers a linear layout.  Margins and padding are used to position but, RelativeLayout is often better.  It needs some investment to learn how to use it properly but many people find RLs easier than LLs.

Comment: Actually I just fixed it. I actually had a relative layout, and changing the Id's caused the stacking, just like the guy below me said. When I changed the layout to linear and changed the Id's, I didn't get stacking.

Comment: To me it seems as if linear is easier IMHO

Comment: So how would you position a control on the right, exactly 10dps from the edge regardless of screen size or density?

Comment: Couldn't you just use right padding (or left) in Linear Layout?

Comment: Well I see, I'll put it this way, with what I'm trying to implement, Linear would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I mean how can changing the ID cause any layout differences????
```

You, probably, are using Relative layout, because it does that. In android there are different layouts for different purposes. Like [Linear Layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html), [Relative Layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html), [Frame Layout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html).

In Relative Layout you place views relative to each-other (which means in reference to id of views), That's why when you move 1 view all view's placed in reference to it also move.

So, place views carefully in RelativeLayout. This is bit difficult for new developers, So, I suggest first think what you want and how you will achieve it than use appropriate layout.

Comment: OH! You are right, I was using relative layout. I changed it to linear and problem solved! Thanks.